# Can't run Android Emulator to debug Xamrarin App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-virtual-device

I'm a newbie on Xamarin and I get stuck when trying to run Xamarin App with Android Emulator.

This is my AVD:

[image]

I can run this AVD fine but slow, if I check to Use Host GPU, it much faster but takes to long to start emulator. But when I debug on Xamrin, it always show this error in emulator:

```
unfortunately launcher3 has stopped
```

or just loading and never complete like this:

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest not using the AVD Manager and instead using the [Xamarin Android Player](https://www.xamarin.com/android-player). It is much faster and is 1000x more reliable than the AVD garbage.

Comment: This is very true. But actually, since AVD introduced x86_64 support (64-bits), the emulators have become much faster.

Comment: @Demitrian O cool. Did not know about that. Will have to give it a try.

Comment: In a similar vein, I would highly recommend using the [Standalone Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx), which is very performant and easy to set up. The only caveats are that you'll need to enable Hyper-V (if you haven't already) and it doesn't play nice if you have OracleBox or similar VM software installed

Comment: @Joe Indeed! Forgot about that one. I have not given that one a try yet. Have not switched to Visual Studio 2015, plus I am running Window within Parallels so virtualization in general is out completely in my Windows environment.